# npm install and gulp fails in cron job

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, cron, gulp

I have shell script where I use npm and gulp after pulling from remote git repo. It passes on manual trigger but fails on cron. Any help is appreciated.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "changing dir"
cd /Users/na/mainrepo

git -C /Users/na/mainrepo/ checkout dev
git -C /Users/na/mainrepo/ fetch
echo "Pulling latest code from git repo"
git -C /Users/na/mainrepo/ pull

for commitid in $(git -C /Users/na/mainrepo/ log --format="%h" -n 2)

do

    echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

    echo "Checkout branch"
    git -C /Users/na/mainrepo/ checkout dev
    echo "git reset hard"
    git -C /Users/na/mainrepo/ fetch --all
    git -C /Users/na/mainrepo/ reset --hard origin/dev
    echo "Checkout commit id: ""$commitid"
    echo git checkout "$commitid"
    git -C /Users/na/mainrepo/ checkout "$commitid"
    echo "Installing dependencies"
    npm install
    echo "Gulpifying the code"
    gulp dev --ver beta2
    manifestversion="beta2"
    basefolder="/Users/na/mainrepo/mainrepo/""$manifestversion"
    basedestfolder="/Users/na/smbneyazee/out/"

    if [ -d "$basefolder" ]; then

        versionrepo=`cat "$basefolder"/version.txt`
        echo "Version in repo: ""$versionrepo"
        destfolder="$basedestfolder""/""$commitid"

        if [ -d "$destfolder" ]; then

            echo "Latest commit are already in place"
            zipname="$versionrepo""_""$commitid"".zip"
            break

        else
            mkdir "$destfolder"
            cp -r "$basefolder" "$destfolder"
            zipname="$versionrepo""_""$commitid"".zip"
            zipdestpath="$basedestfolder""/""$zipname"
            echo "Making new zip from latest commit"
            echo zip -r "$zipdestpath" "$destfolder"
            zip -r "$zipdestpath" "$destfolder"
        fi

    else

        echo "$basefolder"" : folder doesn't exist, exiting"
    fi

done
```

Output Snippet:

```
Installing dependencies
/Users/na/GulpBuild.sh: line 25: npm: command not found
Gulpifying the code
/Users/na/GulpBuild.sh: line 27: gulp: command not found
Manifest Version in repo: 0.32
```

Cron details:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /Users/na/GulpBuild.sh >> /Users/na/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

As you can see, it cannot find npm or gulp. And it is not because I don't have either of them not installed. I have all necessary things satisfied and the script is running on manual trigger.

Comment: Hi! cron default PATH is /usr/bin:/bin check where git/npm are located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user which executes the cron job has no `PATH` set and therefore can't find the mentioned files. Normally files like `.bashrc` aren't sourced when started by cron. You can [change that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/cron-ignores-variables-defined-in-bashrc-and-bash-profile) if necessary.

Find the files by executing `which npm` and `which gulp`. Add the given paths to your file.

For example, change:

```
npm install
```

to

```
/usr/local/bin/npm install
```